# Recovering Hotmail attachments deleted when messaged moved between folders in Thunderbird imap

Tags: thunderbird, data-recovery, imap, attachments, outlook.com

When connecting to Hotmail through Thunderbird imap, moving messages between folders strips the content of attachments (resulting in an empty file object). Since no message was deleted, their 'recover deleted messages' function isn't applicable. Is any recovery possible?

Comment: Log in to Hotmail web interface and see if the attachments are on the email. If there isn't and Thunderbird also shows no attachment then I think you've lost it for good and will have to have the message re-sent.

Comment: Was the first try and how I caught the problem. It returned the popup: 'One or more of the attachments in this message could not be retrieved. Please contact the email sender.' Unfortunately, I did a spring-organizing, and only after several days found this out, which means most of my messages were affected. This is a pretty bad bug on Hotmail's part. I'd rather they prohibited the IMAP/Thunderbird connection than have access and allow users to inadvertently delete most of their attachments. Additionally, this problem does not occur in GMail/Thunderbird. Can Hotmail restore?